# Cant configure laravel vite, on nginx on docker

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, vite, laravel-vite

I cant configure laravel vite, on nginx on docker.
How should I configure nginx and vite to make them work?

My docker image and configs:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
 
services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Nginx.dockerfile
        ports:
            -   8098:8098
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/laravel-docker
        links:
            - fpm
    fpm:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Fpm.dockerfile
        volumes:
            -   ./:/var/www/laravel-docker 
            - type: "bind" 
              source: "/tmp"
              target: "/tmp"
        links:
            -   mysql
    mysql:
        platform: linux/x86_64 
        image: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        ports:
        -   3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            #MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
        volumes:
            - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
 
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
 
volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

Fpm.dockerfile

```
ROM php:8.0-fpm
 
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip 
 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
 
ADD docker/conf/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
 
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql pdo_mysql mysqli
 
WORKDIR /var/www/laravel-docker
```

vhosts.conf

```
server {
    listen 8098;
    listen [::]:8098;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/laravel-docker/public;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV local;
    }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js','resources/css/style.css'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        port: 8098,
        host: 'localhost'
    },
});
```

When i run "npm run dev" vite renders resources like this:

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:8098/@vite/client"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8098/resources/css/style.css" /></head>
```

but there is 404 on the http://localhost:8098/resources/css/style.css